# Integrate external routing for omni channel (connected app vs. API)

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, service-cloud-console, isv, omnichannel

We are building a managed package ISV app for a customer that wants to route Service cloud Cases based on its own algorithm (their backend). I am quite new to **Service Cloud** and **OmniChannel** but found this [document describing that recommended approach](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/omnichannel_external_routing_integrate.htm):

1. Create a Routing Configuration and Queue for External Routing
2. Create a `PushTopic` for `PendingServiceRouting`
3. Listen to the `PushTopic`
4. Create `AgentWork`

I'm a little confused because this (at least in an **ISV** setting where multiple customer orgs connect to a single backend) would require a lot of security (like a packaged `Connected App`) to safely (security review stable) allow the backend to reach into the org to learn about Agents, Cases, Skills, etc.

Is this just one approach, or the approach you use when there are only ONE org and ONE backend? Could I also implement that without `PushTopics` and `SOAP API` access and instead send all the relevant information to the backend via a custom REST API?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  We're starting to research supporting Service Cloud omni channel as a managed package and not sure where to start

Comment: No nothing. Sorry.